# Setting MIMETYPE of Data for ContactsContract in Adapter or Fragment

Tags: android, mime-types, android-cursoradapter, contactscontract, android-cursorloader

In my application I am seeking to display contact details of

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE
```

Within the ContactsContract, the MIMETYPE is used to choose the identity of the column of most of the useful data from the phone.

I am seeking to display the job title of the contacts in my listview. I have used the SQL Injection of IN for the WHERE/SELECTION clause with the code below.

```
 private static final String SELECTION =
            ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
```

This works however because it is in the where clause it removes items that do not have a value here which largely minimizes the number of item in the list.

Like mentioned above I'm seeking to find how to set the MIMETYPE of the cursor either in my CursorLoader or in the my CursorAdapter.

The binding adapter method looks like this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
    String profession = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
    String contactID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID));
    Uri contactURI = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            Integer.parseInt(contactID));
    viewHolder.setProfession(profession);
    viewHolder.setURI(contactURI);
```

The CursorLoader simply looks like this. FROM_COLUMNS contains basic data including

```
 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE


 return new CursorLoader(
                        getContext(),
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        FROM_COLUMNS,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're now doing is basically display a list of **all job-titles** on the Contacts DB, and get the contact-ID for each job-title.

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to achieve is to display a list of **all contacts** on the DB, and if a contact contains a job-title, to display it next to the contact?

If so, you can't create a CursorLoader over `Data.CONTENT_URI` as it contains one item per data, i.e. each contact may contain many data rows.

You can avoid using CursorLoader altogether, and run through all items in `Data` - storing them in memory in some HashMap, and then creating a ListView/RecyclerView adapter to display the HashMap on screen.

Here's code to get you started (consider creating a custom object to contain Contact info instead of the List of strings i'm using below):

```
Map<Long, List<String>> contacts = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();

String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1 };
// select only contacts that have at least one phone, email or job
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "', '" + Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String mime = cur.getString(2); // type of data: email / phone / company
    String data = cur.getString(3); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234

    switch (mime) {
        case Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            kind = "phone"; 
            break;
        case Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            kind = "email";
            break;
        case Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE: 
            kind = "job";
            break;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + data);

    // add info to existing list if this contact-id was already found, or create a new list in case it's new
    List<String> infos;
    if (contacts.containsKey(id)) {
        infos = contacts.get(id);
    } else {
        infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        infos.add("name = " + name);
        contacts.put(id, infos);
    }
    infos.add(kind + "= " + data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. One of the benefits for using the loader is the added security as well as the fact that Loader has a ContentObserver built into it which I am enjoying as well. May have to continue research to dig into the best approach. This may be helpful to someone https://gist.github.com/piyush-malaviya/c423a5531846fa8143a0432382296a75

Comment: not sure what is the security benefit, but the contentObserver should be real easy to add

Comment: I believe the core problem is with the selection clause because I am seeking to retrieve not only the items that have a profession but also those that do not. Any clue here?

Comment: `MIMETYPE IN (...)` is an OR selection, so you should get ALL contacts (except for contacts that have no phones, emails or organization)

Comment: I went with the Map approach and custom object and was able to make good progress.